# Group $G$ of order $24$ that is either $S_4$ or $G/Z(G)$ is $A_4$.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

A group is $p$-*closed* if it has only one Sylow $p$-subgroup.

**Theorem**: Let $G$ be a group of order 24 that is not 3-closed. Then either $G\cong S_4$ or $G/Z(G)\cong A_4$.

Proof. $G$ acts on $$ \Omega:=\operatorname{Syl}_3 G$$ by conjugation. Since $G$ is not 3-closed Sylow's Theorem gives $|\Omega|=4$. Thus, there exists a homomorphism $\varphi:G\to S_4$ such that $$\operatorname{Ker}\varphi =\bigcap_{S\in\Omega} N_G(S)=: N.$$
$G/N$ is a subgroup of $S_4$ and $|N|$ a divisor of $\frac{24}{4}=6$. If $|N|\in\{3,6\}$, then $N$ and thus also $G$ is 3-closed, a contradiction. The case $N=1$ yields $G\cong S_4$, and the case $|N|=2$ implies $N=Z(G)$ and $G/N\cong A_4$. $\square$

I don't understand the case $|N|=2$. Obviously $Z(G)\leq N_G(S)$ for every $S\in Syl_3 G$ and so $Z(G)\leq N$. Is it that $Z(G)=2$? And why is $G/N$ isomorphic to $A_4$? This seems even more difficult to prove!

Comment: This is from *"The Theory of Finite Groups: An Introduction,"* by Kurzweil and Stellmacher.

Comment: Also, please refrain from using pictures like yours here. They're difficult to search and are less user-friendly than typed-up $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 1):

If $|N|=2$, you proved that $Z(G)<N$. But any normal subgroup of order 2 must be contained in the center (see for example, [Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of order 2 in group $G$, show that $K$ lies in the centre of $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267443/let-k-be-a-normal-subgroup-of-order-2-in-group-g-show-that-k-lies-in-the)), so $N<Z(G)$ and thus $N=Z(G)$.

Now $G/N$ is a subgroup of $S_4$ that has order 12. Therefore $[S_4:G/N]=2$, and it is a very common exercise (see [$A_n$ is the only subgroup of $S_n$ of index $2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27024/a-n-is-the-only-subgroup-of-s-n-of-index-2)  ) that the unique subgroup of $S_n$ of index 2 is $A_n$.

We conclude $G/N\cong A_4$.